# Pausing Diablo III

Tags: diablo-iii

In the original games you could pause single player.  In Diablo III, you are always connected and there is no real "single player" mode.  Is it still possible to pause the game?  I haven't been game (no pun intended) to test it out in anger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you press <kbd>Escape</kbd> while no other player is connected, the game pauses, just like many other single-player games.

Comment: I presume this does not hold true while in a party?

Comment: I also noticed that opening certain screens caused this, most notably the achievements screen.

Comment: @Foxtrot correct, you cannot pause when other players are connected.

Comment: while in a party it'll appear a small hourglass in your head. So you can know if someone is 'in-pause'

Comment: Hmm... I think mine didn't pause with just pressing `ESC`, but I'm not sure. Will try tonight.

Comment: What happens if someone joins while the game is paused?

Comment: On two occasions today I hit `ESC` in a single-player game (not in town) and left the computer for 30+ minutes. When returning both times, the game had displayed a message saying that I had been disconnected from the game. This has never happened when playing.

Answer (score 5):

You can definitely press Escape for pause but keep in mind that game will kick you in about 10 minutes of "Pause" with timeout error. That's not a real pause!