# Is it safe to leave my character idling if I suddenly have to go?

Tags: diablo-iii

Since there is no saving in Diablo 3, suppose I suddenly have to go do something with no previous warning (having a 2 year old son will do that to you), and I'm in a relatively safe area (no boss fight), can I leave my character idling in a corner with no fear of monsters walking by and attacking her?

Alternatively, can I use my town portal and idle there? What happens when I teleport back? Do the monsters respawn?

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking regarding playing with friends, since [in single-player you can just pause](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66457/pausing-diablo-iii)...

Comment: For what it's worth, you can idle for *hours* without getting kicked from the game, too. Blizzard apparently isn't detecting and booting idlers, or if they are, it's a *really* high timeout.

Comment: @Oak, actually... I didn't know you could pause it (since it doesn't with just pressing `ESC` I assumed it was not possible. Thank you for making me feel dumb!

Comment: @Sterno - I time out for idling after about 20 minutes.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I wonder if that's new. I had my wife's account idled for at least 4 hours (in a solo game, in Tristram) on Wednesday night. She was also alt-tabbed away, but I can't imagine that actually made a difference.

Comment: It doesn't really matter unless in Hardcore, **never idle outside town** in HC mode (nor in town, if others in team are the type to train mobs on an afk'er)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF you are soloing you can "Pause" the game by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd> Also you can Press <kbd>Y</kbd> and go in pause as well

You can also use <kbd>T</kbd> and head back to the city (If you are not in a boss fight/dungeon) and return for your spot after that.

Comment: Note: those are the default Key for option, achievement and recall (respectively)

Comment: This is not my experience - I've timed out after only 45m or so of idle (with the game *paused*, even).

Comment: @IanPugsley maybe it was because the game *was* paused

Comment: Nope - same thing has happened with it unpaused. Initially, it happened, and so I paused to check to see if it still happened.

Comment: Ok, removing the edit then.

Comment: Will the game be saved if I leave the game while "I" am in a town?

Comment: @Martin take a look at this [When is the game saved, and how?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66238/when-is-the-game-saved-and-how).

Answer (score 5):

In the beta, it was discovered that other players can kite monsters even into town.  If you are playing with other people, idling is **only** safe if you are in an area that requires you to "zone in" (such as Deckard Cain's house in Act 1).

For solo games, the safest way to idle is to pause the game, as others have mentioned.

Comment: This is valuable addition

Answer (score 4):

Monsters do you not respawn unless you leave and rejoin your game, or do something that causes an area to reset(which wouldn't happen while idling). If you're sure the area immediately around you is clear of monsters, you should be fine. Monsters don't tend to wander to far from their spawn point.