# Can I idle out of a game?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to leave my character idling if I suddenly have to go?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66873/is-it-safe-to-leave-my-character-idling-if-i-suddenly-have-to-go)

I was playing with friends and left to do an errand, and I was still in town when I returned about a half hour later (possibly even longer). Is it possible to timeout from inactivity (or "idle out"), kicking me back to the main menus? (If so, how long does it take?) Or can I idle indefinitely? Is there something simple to do to prevent idling out while away?

Answer (score 1):

The server will disconnect you after 20~30 minutes.

You won't be thrown to the main menu without a message window telling you about the disconnect though.

Comment: "won't be" should be "will be"?

Comment: no, the point was that you will not be thrown out _without a message_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Diablo can disconnect you eventually but it seems that there isn't a set time limit. It may depend on demand on the servers, i.e. how many other players are connected.

I've been disconnected a couple of times while idling, but others I left for longer and haven't been.